# Build slice objetcs from subscript notation

Tags: python, slice

I would like to get slice objects from subscript notation. So far, I have used a hacky trick to exploit Python built-in subscript to slice conversion features:

```
class Slice:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item
```

For example, `Slice()[1:2]` will return `slice(1,2,None)`.

Does anyone know of a more straightforward way?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Python has a built in slice function, what exactly are you trying to slice?

Comment: Why does it have to be from subscript notation?  Python has a built-in [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) function that lets you construct slice objects directly:  `my_slice = slice(1, 2)`.

Comment: I doesn't _have_ to be in subscript notation. I like that because it allows you to construct many slices from a compact notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* use subscript notation, then your current solution is the most compact besides maybe a dynamic class created with [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> Slice = type('', (), {'__getitem__': lambda _, x: x})()
>>> Slice[1:2]
slice(1, 2, None)
>>> Slice[1:2:3]
slice(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

But code like this is usually hard to understand/maintain/extend/etc.

Instead, I would recommend that you use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), which allows you to create slice objects directly:

```
>>> slice(1, 2)
slice(1, 2, None)
>>> slice(1, 2, 3)
slice(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

The built-in was made specifically for this purpose (well, that and a few others such as type-checking with `isinstance`) and is therefore very portable as well as pythonic.